# Different ways to instantiate classes

Tags: c#, constructor, new-operator, var

Aside from personal preference is there any difference between:

```
SomeClass SomeInstance = new SomeClass();

SomeClass SomeInstance = new();
```

and

```
var SomeInstance = new SomeClass();
```

Comment: they all result in the exact same IL.

Comment: Nope, although on older versions of C# some of those won't even compile

Comment: I don't know whether it's years of using the `var` version but I still prefer it over `new()`

Comment: What doesnt work is `var SomeInstance = new ();` :D

Comment: arguably you should be injecting an instance from your DI container ;-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new()` was introduced in C#9 for use with type inference so you don't have to keep specifying it if the type is already known.
Example is if you are creating a

`new List<Something>() { new Something()}`

then each `new Something()` can be changed to `new()`

`new List<Something>() { new()}`

thus less syntax :)

The Microsoft release doc is here to explain it better than i could. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new